# Open jQueryUI DatePicker on current month, regardless of what date is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The DatePicker will always open on the date which is selected in the input. I need to open DatePicker at the current month, no matter what date is selected in the input.

I have tried the following, but it will change the value of the input as well, which is not desirable.

```js
beforeShow: function() {
  $(input).datepicker("setDate", "0");
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this functionality is available in the jQueryUI datepicker control, nor can it be amended to have this behaviour without changing the selected date. If you have to have this behaviour (which sounds like it could be very annoying for your users if they select a date far away from the current date) then you'll need to use a different library - assuming one even exists that can do this as I've never seen one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it for a while I did it this way:

```
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function() {  
            var date = new Date();
            inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
            inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
            inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
            $.datepicker._adjustDate(input);
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ouw8p9gc/

Answer (score 1):

It is not ideal, but a workaround could be to enable the today button panel, hide it with css and trigger click this button when the calendar is rendered:

```
$('#datepickerText').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true
});


$('#datepickerText').on('click',function(){
    $('.ui-datepicker-current').trigger('click');
});
```

css:

```
.ui-datepicker-buttonpane{
   display:none; 
}
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03hf5x6t/